# Проверка двух значений в одной таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица dating . 
В ней такие столбцы: id, user_id, user_id_from, status.
Нужно вывести данные если есть две записи

```
user_id=1, user_id_from=35, status=1
user_id=35, user_id_from=1, status=1
```

Это взаимные лайки типа, если обе записи есть - показываем каждому из них кто поставил им лайк.
Второй день мучаюсь, пробовал INNER JOIN, пытался с GROUP BY, пробовал кучу условий - н и ч е г о.

Вот моя последняя попытка:

```
include 'bd.php';
$usrid=$_SESSION['id'];
$qqq2 = "SELECT dating.*, users.*
FROM dating INNER JOIN  users ON (dating.`status`='1')
WHERE dating.`user_id_from`='$usrid' AND dating.`user_id`=users.`id`  ";
$result7 = mysql_query($qqq2);
while($row7 = mysql_fetch_array($result7)){  
echo '<a class="avatar" href="#"><img src="/files/'; echo $row7['photo']; echo '" >'; echo $row7['login'];echo '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то...

БД

```
num=1, id=Ваня, to_id=Андрей

num=2, id=Андрей, to_id=Ваня
```

Вот пример

```
$query = $bds->query("SELECT * FROM test");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$user1 = $bds->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE num=1");
$arr1 = mysqli_fetch_array($user1);

$user2 = $bds->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE num=2");
$arr2 = mysqli_fetch_array($user2);

for ($i=1;$i<$row;$i++)
{
    if ($arr1['id'] == $arr2['to_id'])
    {
        echo 'Совпали значения';
         //Что-то делаем
        die();
    }
}
```

Результат

```
Совпали значения
```

P.S
Разложил в стиле "какашечного кода" для понимания так сказать. В идеале будет выглядеть по другому :)